# Unable to retrieve the date by using the following query

Tags: sql, oracle

Unable to get the required results using below query

[image]

```
First_Name Last_Name Email          Order_Date Sale_Amt
shaun      wong      xxxx@gmail.com 5/1/2019    $5 
shaun      wong      xxxx@gmail.com 7/1/2019    $7    
shaun      wong      xxxx@gmail.com 9-1-2019    $7 
mark       young     xxxx@yahoo.com 12-1-2018   $35 
mark       young     xxxx@yahoo.com 22-1-2018   $45 
mark       young     xxxx@yahoo.com 15-1-2018   $75
```

sql,Oracle

```
select *
from sampletable test1
where test1.Order_date = (
    SELECT MAX(Order_date)
    FROM sampletable test2
    where test2.First_Name = 'shaun'
  ) 
  AND test1.sale_Amt = (
    select SUM(sale_Amt)
    FROM sampletable test2
    where test2.First_Name = 'shaun'
  );
```

I need to get the latest record for each order and i need the total sum of all sale_Amt for each latest record

I wrote the below query to pull the distinct records.

```
select distinct * 
from OrdersTable 
where Order_date IN ( SELECT MAX(Order_date) As Last_Order_Date FROM OrdersTable GROUP BY First_name)
```

Comment: You mention Oracle but have tagged mysql... which DBMS are you using.  Also, please add you code to your question and remove the image.  Thanks

Comment: I figured out to get the distinct records based on order _date but i am unable to sum up the column values .

Comment: First_Name Last_Name Email Order_Date Sale_Amt
      
shaun     wong xxxx@gmail.com 5/1/2019 $5 
shaun     wong xxxx@gmail.com 7/1/2019 $7 
shaun      wong xxxx@gmail.com  9-1-2019 $7
mark      young xxxx@yahoo.com  12-1-2018 $35 
mark     young xxxx@yahoo.com   22-1-2018 $45 
mark     young xxxx@yahoo.com  15-1-2018 $75

Comment: I attached the sample dataset and i wrote the below query to pull the distinct records .select distinct * from OrdersTable where Order_date IN ( SELECT MAX(Order_date) As Last_Order_Date FROM OrdersTable GROUP BY First_name)

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what are looking for?  This is Oracle...

```
select first_name, last_name, email, order_date , (SELECT SUM(sale_amt)  
                                    FROM sls_detail
                                    WHERE  first_name = ED.first_name and last_name = ED.last_name AND email = ED.email
                                    GROUP BY first_name, last_name, email) sale_amt
from (select ed.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by first_name, last_name,email
                               order by order_date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from sls_detail ed
     ) ED

where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: No luck .I tired it  but nothing working out .even mysql also fine